# Can JMESPATH perform a "contains X or Y" search/filter?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, sdk, jmespath

Is it possible to move the `preg_match` search below into the JMESPATH search filter using `contains`? I found an example of `contains` in the [JMESPATH tutorial](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html), but I'm not sure if the syntax supports combining filter strings somehow using `OR`.

```
  $s3_results = $s3_client->getPaginator('ListObjects', ['Bucket' => $config['bucket']]);
  // Narrow S3 list down to files containing the strings "css_" or "js_".
  foreach ($s3_results->search('Contents[].Key') as $key) {
    if (preg_match("/(css_|js_)/", $key)) {
      $s3_keys[] = $key;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the document is in a format something like this:

```
{
    "Contents": [
        {
            "Key": "some/path/css_example",
             ...
        },
        {
            "Key": "another/path/js_example",
             ...
        },
        {
            "Key": "blah/blah/other_example",
             ...
        }
    ]
}
```

(I would check but I don't have AWS credentials to hand and it's surprisingly hard to find examples of the JSON format of an S3 list-objects response.)

Try the query:

```
Contents[].Key|[?contains(@, 'css_') || contains(@, 'js_')]
```

In this case, `Contents[].Key` selects just the keys (as in your example). The pipe `|` is used to reset the projection so that we operate on the whole list rather than on each key separately. The `[?...]` filters the list to select only the keys that meet the boolean condition. The `contains` function can be used in several ways but we use it here to see if the first argument, as strings (`@`, the current item in the list) contains the second argument, the substring we're searching for. We combine two uses of the `contains` function with the or operator `||`, so that an item matches if *either* condition is true.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, the [or expression](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#or-expressions) is something that does exist in JMESPath.

But then, you could even go further and drop your for loop entirely and fetch the keys using [functions expression](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#functions).

Given the data:

```json
{
  "Contents": [
    {
      "Key": [
        "css_foo",
        "js_bar",
        "brown_fox"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Key": [
        "js_foo",
        "css_bar",
        "lazy_dog"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then

```php
$keys = $s3_results->search(
  'Contents[].Key[?contains(@, `js_`) == `true` || contains(@, `css_`) == `true`]'
);
```

Would give you the following two dimensional array (because there is two contents):

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(7) "css_foo"
    [1] =>
    string(6) "js_bar"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(6) "js_foo"
    [1] =>
    string(7) "css_bar"
  }
}
```

---

Or even simpler, since `contains` returns `true` or `false`, already:

```php
$keys = $s3_results->search(
  'Contents[].Key[?contains(@, `js_`) || contains(@, `css_`)]'
);
```